# How to get parameters values to the post build projects in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a parameterized jenkins project. It is has a post build on other project action. Its contain predefined parameters. And also it contains another project for post build action.

I want to pass my first project param values to the 3rd project.
How should I do it?

```html
1st prj  params-->------------------->------------------->-----------------
 |-post build on other project---- 2nd prj                                |
                                     |- post build on other project---- 3rd prj
```

Comment: Are you not able to pass it to the 3rd project through the 2nd project ?

Comment: @ben5556 Then how can I got those 1st prj params to 3rd prj?

Comment: When triggering project 2 from project1 send the parameters along in the post build step. Assign the parameter values from project1 to some variables in project2. Re-send the variable values as parameters to project3. Is that what you are trying to do or did I understand you incorrectly ?

Comment: Exactly it is the task. How to do it? Is it possible to pass the values without passing those values to properties file and read it?

Comment: Yes, it is possible using Jenkins build step to trigger a project and pass parameter values to the downstream project. See https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/